# Any way to loop over a SortedSet without an Iterator or save index position?

Tags: c#, .net, loops, xna

I want to loop over a SortedSet without having to save the actual position in my code.

In [the official .NET documention](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd412070.aspx) I notice that a [First()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb291976.aspx) method exists but I didn't find a `Next<T>()` method or a kind of (`getNext`, `goNext`, `Iterate`...).

What I want to code is something like this :

```
private SortedSet<Frame> frames;

[...]

public Frame getNextFrame() {
    if (frames.Next<Frame>()) //didnt exists
    {
        return frames.Current<Frame>() //didnt exists
    } else {
        return frames.First<Frame>();
    }
}
```

*Frame struct :*

```
public struct Frame
{
    Rectangle zone;
    TimeSpan duration;

    public Frame(Rectangle z, TimeSpan ts)
    {
        duration = ts;
        zone = z;
    }

}
```

Comment: you only want to see the first or the second item in the list? because you can just iterate over a set with the foreach statement but I am not sure if that's what you are looking for

Comment: What type is `frames`? You're going to want it to implement IList<Frame> if you want to avoid performance hits.

Comment: I want to browse all the list, my question is does exist any way to have a containable which keep its position.

Comment: `IEnumerator<T> for the SortedSet<T>` look at the link you posted and click on `IEnumerable and the GetEnumerator()` you need to understand these first in my opinion

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are looking for is the `IEnumerator<T>` for the `SortedSet<T>`, you can get this with  [`SortedSet<T>.GetEnumerator()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd382041.aspx).

So you can do something like the following:

```
public class MyClass
{
    private readonly IEnumerator<Frame> _enumerator;

    public MyClass(SortedSet<Frame> frames)
    {
        _enumerator = frames.GetEnumerator();
    }

    public Frame GetNextFrame()
    {
        // If there is no next item, loop back to the beginning 
        // you probably won't want this, but a call to MoveNext() is required
        // it's up to you what to do if there is no next item.
        if(!_enumerator.MoveNext())
            _enumerator.Reset();

        return _enumerator.Current;
    }
}
```

Although I'm surprised you can't just utilise the much simpler [foreach](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ttw7t8t6%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) loop:

```
SortedSet<Frame> frames = ...;
foreach(Frame frame in frames)
{
    // Do something with each frame
}
```

Comment: You got the point, IEnumerator is what I need to do the job. For the end of your message, I don't want to browse all the SortedList but get the actual Frame to draw on screen.